# Obfuscar with Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, obfuscation, obfuscar

Has anyone had any success obfuscating Xamarin.iOS apps using [Obfuscar](https://docs.obfuscar.com/)?

It looks like it's supported but the the documentation for configuring a project is almost non existent.

Comment: iOS app deployment is native and does not require extra obfuscation if you don't know yet, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/internals/architecture#aot

Comment: Thank you but does this also mean you can't get to any string resources embedded in the IPA by using a tool like ILSpy? One of my primary objectives to obscure things like API endpoints stored in a string resource

Comment: https://docs.obfuscar.com/getting-started/basics.html#caveat You cannot protect string resources via obfuscation tools, so if that's your primary objective you think it the wrong way. In general, any protection just raises the bar of reverse engineering a little bit, so you can never hide any secrets. You should keep that in mind.

Comment: Thanks for that. I believe you're the author/maintainer for the project? Would you mind having a look at another issue I ran into with a Android build?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71747985/xamarin-android-crashes-after-running-obfuscar-visual-studio-for-mac. TIA!